# Объясните почему результат различается (массивы int и char)

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    char *a = new char[5]{'a','b','c','d','e'};
    cout<<&a[1] << "\n";
    cout <<&a[1]+1<< "\n";
    cout <<&a[1]+2<< "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:
bcde
cde
de

```
int main()
{
    int *a = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};
    cout<<&a[1] << "\n";
    cout <<&a[2]<< "\n";
    cout <<&a[3]<< "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:
0x561864af9eb4
0x561864af9eb8
0x561864af9ebc

**Вопрос: Почему в случае int выводятся адреса каждого элемента массива, а в случае char
выводится "оставшийся" массив?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в первом случае выводится `char*`, а во втором - `int*`.

Перегрузка оператора вывода для типа `char*` интерпретирует данные как С-строку (традиционно `char*` используется в основном для этой цели — работы со строками.

В случае `int*` выводятся значения указателей.

Кстати, на ваше счастье после `'e'` находится нулевой байт, а то вы могли бы получить более длинные строки...